# The same code snippet works well as a standalone script but gets stuck when running in a Jupyter Notebook cell. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm using OpenCV 4.7.0 on macOS 13 with an M1 chip. The following Python code works well as a standalone script, where it captures camera input and renders it on the screen. Pressing 'q' quits the program:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, when I try running the same code in a Jupyter Notebook cell, it gets stuck indefinitely after rendering the camera feed when I press 'q'.

[image]

I have considered a few potential factors causing this issue:

1. Jupyter Notebook: There could be a compatibility issue or a bug specific to Jupyter Notebook that causes the code to get stuck when 'q' is pressed.
2. OpenCV: There might be an issue with OpenCV. I have already fetched the latest code from GitHub, built and installed it.
3. Incorrect usage: It's possible that there is an error in how I'm using the code in the Jupyter Notebook environment.

Any suggestions on where I should dig deeper to troubleshoot this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: The situation with Jupyter is certainly more complicated, because Jupyter is itself a GUI application that has its own message loop.  It doesn't run your script as a standalone application, it runs it as part of its own process.  However, there is evidence that others have been able to make this work.   **IF** you replace the `waitKey` call by, say, `time.sleep(1)`, does it mostly work?

Comment: if the waitkey disappears, the imshow window will remain unresponsive for sure. waitkey doesn't "wait" (sleep is not a substitute), it processes GUI events for the GUI library used by opencv.